# Unable to import Hugging Face transformers

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I have been using transformers fine up until today. However, when I imported the package today, I received this error message:

```
In Transformers v4.0.0, the default path to cache downloaded models changed from '~/.cache/torch/transformers' to '~/.cache/huggingface/transformers'. Since you don't seem to have overridden and '~/.cache/torch/transformers' is a directory that exists, we're moving it to '~/.cache/huggingface/transformers' to avoid redownloading models you have already in the cache. You should only see this message once.

Error: Destination path '/home/user/.cache/huggingface/transformers/transformers' already exists
```

I have tried to install and uninstall the package but still unable to make it work.

Any suggestions to fix this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears to be a cache file, simply move the /huggingface/ dir to /huggingface.bak

Then you should be able to re-run the script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joshua, the above problem was resolved the following command:

```
  mv ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers ~/.cache/huggingface-tmp
```